# Flurry Analytics user paths trough event params

Tags: flurry, flurry-analytics

I have installed flurry analytics and wish to analyze user paths around screens. I have an event named screen-view and inside this event, I have event parameters with screen names. But in "explorer" tab, when I choose an event to see user paths I can't choose any parameters. Is it possible to view user paths by event parameters in flurry? Or maybe there is any way to see, how are users iterating with the application?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Currently, user paths do not allow for this level of granularity, only event-level. You can build funnels if you are interested in if your users have navigated your screens in a specific order.